# Pass value from @Input to provided injection token

Tags: angular8, angular-material-datetimepicker

How can i pass value from component @Input to provided InjectionToken ? Currently i have

```
@Component({
  selector: 'a-datetime',
  providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter},
    {provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, 
      useValue: {strict: false, useUtc: ???}}, <-- Pass value from component @Input
  ]
})
export class DatetimeInputComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() utc: boolean;

  constructor() {
  }
```

Idea is to use componet like:

```
<a-datetime [utc]="true or false"> depending on use case.
```

My current solution is to have / copy two components, one with `<a-datetime-with-useutc-true` and other `<a-datetime-with-useutc-false` and then i have `<a-datetime` where i decide which one to show with `ngIf*`

Im looking for more elegant solution. Can anyone point me to right direction ?